# Is it possible to initialize new object in constructor's initialization list and reference it?

Tags: c++, initialization

**Client** is the top class of DLL so I need to create and pass new Session object in it's initialization to create **requestor** and **session** should be assigned to same Session. Is it possible?

```
class Session
{
public:Session() {}

};

class Requestor
{
public: Requestor(const Session& session) {};
};

class Client
{
public:Client()
{
    Session newSession;
    requestor = Requestor(newSession);
}

private:
    Session session;
    Requestor requestor;
};
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `session` member you already have to initialize `requestor`?

Comment: If you want them to refer to the same object, you will need pointers.

Comment: @kamilk Plain nonsense, there aren't any pointers needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but somewhat fragile in that the initialization order depends on the declaration order of the members. Provided these remain as in your example, you can simply do

```
class Client()
{
public:
    Client() : requestor(session) // session is implicitly default constructed
    {}
private:
    Session session;
    Requestor requestor;
};
```

Note: it isn't clear why you are instantiating a local `Session` object in your constructor. I am assuming that is a mistake.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that's because I used to c#.

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstood what OP meant by 'assigned to same Session' but depending on what `Requestor` will do in its constructor, `Client` and `Requestor` will likely each have a copy of `Session` rather than 'being assigned to the same one`.

Comment: @kamilk That depends on the internals `Requestor`, which are not shown. It doesn't depend on `Client` or its constructor.